# How to output json data as an array and not set of objects in Mapping Dataflow Datafactory?

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

[image]

I am trying to output my data after transformations in mapping dataflow to a json file. But the records ends up as separate set of json objects and not joined by commas enclosed in array as shown below:

file contents:
{k1:v1,k2:v2}
{k1:v3,k2:v4}

[image]

Expected:
[{k1:v1,k2:v2},
{k1:v3,k2:v4}]

[image]

This is causing a problem while reading as it is not a valid json. The same problem can be fixed in copy activity as there is a setting to output as array of objects and not set of objects.

Can anyone help pls..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still stuck into this, i will answer it anyway.

You can use the Azure Data Factory Data Flow Flatten mapping, unroll by and unroll root. more information found in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten

Comment: Seems like Flatten formatter works only within a row, not across the row.

Comment: How would this help?  This seems to flatten objects into a less ideal JSON structure - when in fact the aim was to create an array of objects? Maybe I'm missing something.